# Квотирование запросов на единицу времени

Tags: php

Есть сервер, на котором пользователи могут одновременно выполнять "тяжелый" запрос.
Существует ли в PHP какая либо возможность квотировать эти запросы относительно единицы времени (не более чем ХХХ запросов одновременно) или хотя бы количественно (не более чем ХХХ в минуту)?

Запрос тяжел для ЦП, а не для базы.

Есть ли какие-либо решения для работы со стеками запросов?

Comment: А сервер у вас Apache или nginx?

Comment: кэшируйте результаты, либо запоминайте время последнего выполнения и сравнивайте дельту с текущим.

Comment: у нас установлен nginx

Comment: кэширование - не вариант. Иначе так бы и сделали. Каждый такой "тяжелый" запрос изменяет массу параметров. А писать дельту хорошая идея. можно разделитьвременной отрезок на порог запросов и высчитать разницу, которую нельзя привышать

Comment: Может использовать lock файл ? Клиент запускает - создаётся lock файл и остальные ждут его.